# How do I get Panel key when I click on extraIcon and the panel is active is Antd Collapse component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a situation, where I need to get the panel key when I click on extra icon (present beside expand arrow/collapse arrow) for the requirement posted below.

When I click on icon, I should remove that panel and add it to the right and vice-versa. To do that, I need to get panel key which I get when Panel is not in active state in `onChange` callback function, but don't get the same when the panel is active.
How do I do this? Please let me know

[image: requirement]

Comment: Can you show us how you rendered the panels?

Comment: @Boris Bezzola: I'm using the similar example provided by antd. 
[antd sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-kowalevski-pgj9u). I need panel key if I click settings icon when panel is active.

Comment: In this specific case I would call the genExtra function with a parameter (the key) so you always know which panel extra is clicked ([updated sample](https://o82ph.csb.app))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific case wanted by @anup-r (modifying an [antd sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-kowalevski-pgj9u)) it is necessary to pass to the genExtra function the key of the panel
See [updated sample](https://o82ph.csb.app)